# Magento 2 How to open custom login popup when click of 'Proceed to Checkout'

Tags: magento2

How to add custom login popup when click on 'Proceed to Checkout' button in minicart as well as in checkout/cart.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create Mixin on `minicart.js` and called `Magento_Customer/js/model/authentication-popup`'s showModal method on MiniCart Proceed to checkout button.

MIXIN: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html

Create `app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js` and add below code:

```
var config = {
    'config': {
        'mixins': {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart': {
                '{VendorName}_{ModuleName}/js/checkout/view/minicart': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Create Mixin Js `app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/view/frontend/web/js/checkout/view/minicart.js`

And below code:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/authentication-popup',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function ($, authenticationPopup, customerData
) {
    'use strict';

    return function (Component) {
        return Component.extend({

            /**
             * @override
             */
            getCartParam: function (name) {
                var self = this;

                if(name === 'possible_onepage_checkout'){
                    $('#top-cart-btn-checkout').click(function (event) {
                        var customer = customerData.get('customer');
                        if (!customer().firstname) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            authenticationPopup.showModal();
                            return false;
                        }
                    });

                }
                return this._super(name);
            },
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but I want to show custom popup when click on 'Proceed to Checkout'.

Comment: have you already create popup?Just need to call it?

Comment: Yes, I created popup for 'Create Acocunt and Login' and I need to call that in 'Proceed To Checkout' button also.

Comment: You have to call your pop-up on the location on `authenticationPopup.showModal();`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Stores->Configuration->Sales->Checkout

Under the checkout options set "Allow Guest Checkout" to "No".

Clear the cache and check if everything works as you need.

Also you can override the pop up in your theme as per your need.